# Is this convolution product reversible?

Tags: convolution, fourier-transform, deconvolution

I am doing an exercise on Fourier transforms and i have the following questions which i really tried to solve myself

> 1. Let $k > 0$ and consider $F_k(x)$ a function with real values where 
>      $$F_k(x)=\begin{cases} 1/k & 0 \le x \le k \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
>      Compute The Fourier transform of $F_k$.
> 2. Considering a $[-\pi, \pi]$ band limited signal, is $u*F_k$ a reversible operation, where * is the convolution operator? If yes,justify you answer with $k$ values where this hypothesis is true.

Now it is easy to answer to question 1 where $F_k(f)=-(1+ e^{ikf})/ikf$
but the challenge is to answer question 2 using the one above. I tried to explicit the convolution product without any significant result.
Any clues?

Comment: The Fourier transform and convolutions have a nice relation.  Have you thought about exploiting that to answer your question?

Comment: Yes.Problem is I don't know how to interpret the result.

Comment: I misread. The convolutive inverse of $\frac{1}{a} 1_{x \in [0,a]}$ is the distribution $T(x)= \delta' \ast a\sum_{n=0}^\infty \delta'(x-n) = a\sum_{n=0}^\infty \delta'(x-an)$